# Time Zone issue in Joomla Virturmat 2.x

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I faced an issue for setting the default time zon in my Joomla shopping cart site.
I am using Joomla 1.7 and VM2.0.6 .

I can set the default time zone from the Joomla administrator but in the VM this time zone is not getting/saving in DB.

I have to set the time zone correctly for orders and registration the VM using a function for getting the time zone.

```
vmJsApi::date("Y-m-d h:i:s ",'LC2',true);
```

Did anybody have some idea about this function it will return the result in 24h format i want that in 12hr and correct the time .

Any link to reference or hint will appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: There are lots of bugs that have been resolved both in Joomla! and Virtuemart since those versions — you would be better off using Joomla! 2.5.8 and Virtuemart 2.0.14 at least by this point. You may find after updating that these issues have been fixed.

Comment: @cppl thanks for reply .But i can't update the site VM have done our site with altering the entire logic of VM.any other option?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry are you saying you modified the core VM files?

Comment: Yes ,Customized entire VM but that is not the issue.I found the problem.In PHP its getting fine but mysql NOW() is creating issue.I am trying to set the zone from cpanel.

Comment: You really put your site / client into danger by sticking with a STS version of Joomla! and with an unupgradeble version of VM.

Comment: @ValentinDespa Thanks for the reply But the requirement is like that so i can't keep normal VM and there is no need of updation we are creating shopping cart product with VM with our own security standards.Any way i got solution for my question.Thanks..